# Put all answers of duplicated questions in one web page?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions

Occasionally, There are duplicate questions for one issue. Should I give my answer to the original question or duplicated one?

In most cases, people are inclined to give their answer to the question with more people viewed due to group psychology, I guess. As a result, the more people viewed question become more popular, however, the other one gets less attention. It seems unfair. This is my immature thought.

So, could the those duplicated question share all of their answers in one web page, and also people viewed?

Comment: I'm not sure I get you. Questions closed as duplicate can't be answered. You can answer only to the original.

Comment: @FlorinGhita it can take while before a question is flagged, by that time it can already have multiple answers. Possibly wonderful answers, better than the original.

Answer (score 3):

Close one of the two as duplicate, and if necessary, add an answer to the one that isn't closed.

Which of the questions you close-vote depends on the quality of the question / answer. Usually, the original one has some answers, and is (at least) decently written. In those cases, you close the dupe.

However, if the dupe is written better and has good answers, while the original is of lower quality, just close-vote the original as dupe of the new question.

If the closed questions answers provide something unique missing in the target, flag a mod for merging naming the specifics.  - [@Deduplicator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3204551/deduplicator)

Comment: mmm, the OP talks about two open questions? In this case you are perfectly right.

Comment: @FlorinGhita: That's how I read it, at least.

Comment: Well, if the closed questions answers provide something unique missing in the target, flag a mod for merging naming the specifics.